# FileNotFoundException: cert\jssecacerts and sessionId = 0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am trying to connect to our server via websocket.  I was able to get the session when I run in IDE. However, the session id is 0.
Also, when I compile and run this using java -jar, I got the following error.  When running in IDE, I don't get this error as I set the working directory to src/main/resources where the cert folder is located:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: cert\jssecacerts (The system cannot find the path specified)
    ...
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.createSSLEnginer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:893)
```

Please advise.

```
    WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
    WebSocketHandler handler = new TextWebSocketHandler();
    WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + getSignedToken());
    URI uri = new URI("wss://<some server>");
    ((StandardWebSocketClient) client).getUserProperties().put(Constants.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PROPERTY, "cert/jssecacerts");
    ((StandardWebSocketClient) client).getUserProperties().put(Constants.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PWD_PROPERTY, Constants.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PWD_DEFAULT);
    WebSocketSession session = client.doHandshake(handler, headers, uri).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding filenotfound, I figured it out.

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("cert/jssecacerts");
...
((StandardWebSocketClient) client).getUserProperties().put(Constants.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PROPERTY, resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
```